# How to detect a string which does not include " using flex?

Tags: regex, string, flex-lexer, lex

Legal string defined by beginning with `"` and ending with `"` and should not contain `"` in the middle. for example:
* `"please help me"` - is legal string
* `"please"help me"` - is illegal string because `help me"` does not start with ".

I want to define a rule in flex to catch a legal strings.
I tried to use this rule but it is not working. 
`\"^[\"].*\"`

Comment: Maybe `"[^"]+"` - but what for exactly?

Answer (score 1):

One way of writing the rule is

```
["][^"]*["]
```

Note that it is not necessary to backslash-escape quote marks (or most other regex characters) if they are inside a character class, so `["]` is exactly the same as `\"`. But I prefer the way it looks :).

What you wrote -- effectively `["][^"].*["]` -- means "a quote, anything but a quote, any string of characters, a quote". What you wanted was "a quote, a string of any character other than quote, a quote", which is expressed by the regular expression above.

If you want to insist that the string contains at least one character, replace the `*` with a `+`.

Comment: first of all thanks, I think your idea is good but in some cases it is permits \n inside the string and it is illegal. do you know how to fix it also ?
for example "help"" (and then enter) make the string wait for another input  and it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks rici, I have managed to reach the solution. for anyone who cares this is the solution ["][^"\n]*["]

Comment: Fwiw, you never mentioned that the string cannot contain newlines. Precise problem descriptions are always better.